# issue with integrating adap.tv vast tags

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, vast

I have tried to integrate and get work my vast tags working. But it's not  working with jw player ads edition. I try to used jw player ads test tester also. Seems it's not working. So, I am looking help for fixed my issue.

My vast tags are:

http://ads.adaptv.advertising.com/a/h/B1aZIz2jP0sdA+S5F3yPKYdqaCO_bZap?cb=[CACHE_BREAKER]&pageUrl=EMBEDDING_PAGE_URL&context=pubid=beachsideus&eov=eov

and

http://ads.adaptv.advertising.com/a/h/sd5niaTAghLjm+tTU_ddLWIz1Q_a8hGWZAca+nZ1pmQ=?cb=[CACHE_BREAKER]&pageUrl=EMBEDDING_PAGE_URL&context=pubid=beachsidemlus&eov=eov

Non of this work for me.

Comment: jsfiddle  setup: http://jsfiddle.net/rtambp8q/2/  and jw player ads tester link:    http://demo.jwplayer.com/ad-tester/

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific. What are you trying to do? what error messages do you see? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: ads not displaying....after few second video is load..what i need is get this tag work..

Answer (score 0):

Your ad tags are simply not serving ads at the moment. You need to reach out to adap.tv about this.

You can test your tags here:

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual

You will see the following error:

```
Events

    (12:27:46 AM) Ads requested
    (12:27:47 AM) adsManagerLoaded
    (12:27:47 AM) adMetadata
    (12:27:49 AM) adError Ad error (code 1001): No ads were found in the ad response. At least one ad is required to be able to load or play.
    (12:27:49 AM) Error: No ads were found in the ad response. At least one ad is required to be able to load or play.
```